# How to Iterate a list whose index has two values and both the values have to be inserted in sql table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I parsed an XML response and saved it in a List. The list looks like

```
[0] = { EmpId = "1999", EmpName = "Wilkins, Alan" }
[1] = { EmpId = "1573", EmpName = "Sean, Jay" }
[2] = { EmpId = "780", EmpName = "James, Parry" }
```

and so on...

How do I iterate this list and insert the values in a sql table database

I wrote the below code. Query is the variable where I'm parsing the XML data.

```
var data = query.ToList();

foreach (var item in data)
{
    _context.Employee.Add(employee);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The data isn't getting inserted in database.

I have a Sql table where the list data is to be saved like below--

```
dbo.[Employee]

EmpID EmpName
1999  Wilkins, Alan
1573  Sean, Jay
780   James, Parry
```

Comment: since this is `async` and just to be sure: are you sure to do correct exception handling? did you debug to see if an exception or something occurs? btw: couldn't you save the changes _after_ the loop, when all entries are in the `Employee` list instead of saving the changes for each single row?

Comment: @Rahul, Do you have `Emp` DbSet Entity in your EF Core DbContext?

Comment: @TanvirArjel - Yes public class EmployeeContext:DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an attribute to the class which you're posting to the database. For, example if you're posting `Employee` type, then add `[Table("EmpTable")]`to that class (EmpTable is the name of the table in the database.

---

**Update**

Like so:

```cs
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
//some properties that are mapped into database columns
}
```

Comment: Table name is dbo.[Employee]

Comment: Then put an attribute `[Table("Employee")]` for the `Employee` class

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a new instance of the employee when creating a new row.

```
var data = query.ToList();

foreach (var item in data)
{
    _context.Employee.Add(new employee { EmpID = item.EmpID , EmpName = item.EmpName} );
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hey can you please explain what is new employee (is this an object of some class). Actually when I'm trying to debug I'm not getting anything saved in EmpID or EmpName

Comment: In your entity framework data context pointing to you DB you should have a public class for each table you are access in the database.  When you create a new record you have to pass in what the database is expecting.  In the case outlined above you are create "_context.Employee.Add" so the public class you are accessing is a Employee.

Comment: For debugging change "await _context.SaveChangesAsync();" to _context.SaveChanges() to see any error being produced

Comment: Code isn't inserting data into database. Not able to debug also.

Comment: @RahulDev What do you mean by not able to debug? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?